# why doesn't django log the specified application?

Tags: python, django, logging

I has some project with application named "work". The directory of the app also named work, and inside apps.py its also named "work", and in INSTALLED_APPS also, etc.

And I try to log just the application into file. So. I have prescribed the following settings in `settings.py`:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'file_logger': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file_logger': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logging.txt',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'work.views': {
            'handlers': ['file_logger'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I initialized inside my `views.py` (`views.py` of `work` app) logger like this:

```
logger = logging.Logger(__name__)
```

where `__name__` is "work.views" (I checked this one via debugger)

and I have some view, which I want to log:

```py
def view_timesheet(request, t_id=None):
    logger.warning('wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww')
    # some code
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

but when I execute the code of this view, nothing is written to the file. With what "wwwwwwwww" gets logged in the console

This confuses me, because it seems to me that I have done everything according to the documentation and everything should work

**A few more details:**

If I write "django" instead of "work.views" all django logs will end up in a file.

This leads me to believe that all my logging settings are correct except for the name of the logger key. I also tried to specify just the application "work" instead of "work.views". It also doesn't change anything

What could be wrong?

P.S: django 3.1.5

Comment: Try using `getLogger` instead - `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Indeed, the reason was this